# How to add two models in single store or single grid based on -ref and date range in customize rally app?

Tags: rally, code-rally

I am a beginner for the development of customized rally app. I have a portfolio item and revisions for every Marketable feature. I have two models PortfolioItem/MarketableFeature and Revision, using this two models I want to make a grid.

I facing issue for combining two models or two stores, for customized rally app models config is not work for any grid. I am confused on how to get revision description and PortfolioItem/MarketableFeature in one grid based on date range and according to MF Id.

i used

```
Rally.ui.grid.Grid
```

for creating a grid,

```
Rally.data.wsapi.Store
```

for creating store and

```
Rally.ui.combobox.FieldValueComboBox
```

for date range(start-date and end-date).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create your grid with the MarketableFeature model.  Is there another way to get the data you need other than loading all the revisions?  This will be very expensive and slow since you'll be making 1 request per grid row in addition to the initial request to populate the portfolio items.

If you do need to do that then you'll probably want to do a combination of these two examples:

Fetching subcollections:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/collections_in_v2-section-collection-fetching

Custom renderer, you can use this to render the Revisions data: 
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/example/custom-data-grid